# How to do, 'Versioning with a History Table' in Flask SQLALchemy. Preferably with some code examples

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, database-versioning

My models are made of flask-sqlalchemy on top of postgresql. I want to keep track of changes made my models.

I have a employees table:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'employees'

id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name          = db.Column(db.String(60))
job_title         = db.Column(db.String(60))
job_type      = db.Column(db.String(60))  # teaching, IT, manager,  
job_location  = db.Column(db.String(60)) 
salary        = db.Column(db.Numeric(15,2))
```

The salary of particular title of employees are increased from 30k to 35k at `dec 2014`, and to 40k at `jan 2016`.

And in some another part of my application say while calculating the revenue and balance sheet, the above `employees.salary` is used in the formula. So I should be able to use old salary 30k for any calculation involving dates before `dec 2014`, and 35k after that, up to `jan 2016`. Any detailed answer with codes related to this example I have is much appreciated, thank you.

I've been searching for how to do this, everywhere with no luck.

Comment: This question is too broad. It's going to require designing your database tables, your queries, and your code to support it. This isn't something that can be covered well in a couple paragraphs. You can't just find a full tutorial for everything on the internet. You're going to have to be able to piece your knowledge together to create larger solutions on your own. This is also a "gimme teh codez" question, so -1 as well.

Comment: I didn't expect anyone givin me exactly the full code.But reasonable sized answers with or without code, as i asked a specific non existing question. Forget my example. The guide lines for making the  'Versioning with a History Table' in other SQL techs exists, but neither the flask-sqlalchemy docs or any other sources, including stack over flow , has got any answers regarding how to do it with Flask alchemy( Outsource i might be wrong).

Comment: I included the simple example( completely fictional), so that people can explain better, on it.

Comment: All i find is this   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#versioning-objects                         i don't know what should i do with this.!